# how to capture a selected button value in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I have bootstrap buttons

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "left" >Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "Middle" >Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "Right">Right</button>
```

when I click the "Left" button I have to capture the id and I have to pass that value into another function in typescript.

Basically what I am doing is:

- I have to capture the value of the button from Html file.

after that, I have to pass that value into app.component.ts file

In ts file: app.component.ts:

I have one  global variable :

```
data = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

if the "id" is "left" then

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
```

if the "id" is "Middle" then

```
data = [3,4,3,4,5,6,7]
```

if the "id" is "Right" then

```
data = [9,8,7,4,5,6]
```

how can I do that..?

Answer (score 0):

on the HTML buttons, call your function with the relevant ID

in your TS, assign relevant value to the data array as per the value which was passed

relevant **HTML**:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "left" (click)="clickedBtn('left')" >Left</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "Middle" (click)="clickedBtn('middle')" >Middle</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" id = "Right" (click)="clickedBtn('right')" >Right</button>
```

relevant **TS**:

```
  clickedBtn(clickedVal){
    switch(clickedVal){
      case 'left':     this.data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]; break;
      case 'middle':     this.data = [3,4,3,4,5,6,7]; break;
      case 'right':     this.data = [9,8,7,4,5,6]; break;
      default: '';
    }
  }
```

working [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x9ipju)